# Maximum number of tasks that can be allocated to cpu's

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given two arrays. One is for tasks (Processes) and each element depicts the amount of cores required to run the task. 2nd array is an array of CPU where each element depicts the no of cores in it.We have to tell how many maximum number of tasks can be allocated.  Example: Task:  [3, 5, 7], Cores: [1, 3, 5] . Here only task 0 and 1 can be allocated to CPU 1 and 2 . So, answer=2.

- I came across this question at one of the websites and I am confused which approach should I use? (I am thinking Greedy approach will work in this case)
- What will be the output if cpu array is 1,3,6 and task array is 3,5,2? (i.e. Can two cpu's be used to perform the same task?)

Comment: `Can two cpu's be used to perform the same task?` is where the confusion begins. You need to fully understand the problem and post the question here. Some other similar question is if a CPU is under utilized can it be used elsewhere?

Comment: SomeDude is right; perhaps the website makes some concessions. This is otherwise an NP complete problem along the lines of the 0-1 integer linear programming problem. A simpler problem might be easily modeled as maximum flow though. You are looking for bipartite graph matching algorithms.

Comment: @SomeDude I am asking the question in reference to this problem. And I am well aware that a cpu can perform multiple task. The confusion is if two cpu can perform 1 task together and the answer is expected to explain with the arrays given.

Comment: Hmm, Is my understanding correct? you are expecting us to clarify a question which only you know where it is coming from, and only you can read its problem statement? Why don't you contact those people in the website?